# How to ExecuteAsync in Dapper when doing an Oracle INSERT ALL

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I have the following SQL command (simplified) assigned to the var `sql`:

```sql
INSERT ALL
    INTO ORACLETBL (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES ('A','B')
    INTO ORACLETBL (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES ('C','D')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

When I do a `conn.Execute(sql);` in a `void` method, the command works correctly.

When I do an `await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql);` in an `async Task` method, against the exact same SQL command, I get the exception "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Is it obvious to anyone what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the statement.

**Edit:**

Maybe that's a solution, too.

```
  string sql = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName) Values (@CustomerName);";

  using (var connection = new SqlConnection("")) {
    connection.Open();

    var affectedRows = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql,
      new[] {
        new {CustomerName = "John"},
        new {CustomerName = "Andy"},
        new {CustomerName = "Allan"}
      }
    );

  }
```

Or try

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Without the semicolon it doesn't work, even in the synchronous manner. But it behaves strangely (appears to end without doing the operation _or_ throwing an exception). Perhaps there is a debugging issue with this in VS2019.

Comment: This issue turned out to be an idiotic attempt to perform the SQL commands while there was a lock on the table, which caused all kinds of unnecessary rabbit trails. Once the underlying issue was addressed ("restart your computer!") the command worked normally with the semicolon removed; no further changes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it throws an exception in one situation but not the other, but it may be related to your using `ExecuteAsync` when you mean to use `QueryAsync`.

Execute is not intended for use with selects, but instead returns the number of affected rows when an operation is performed.

In the [ExecuteAsync documentation](https://dapper-tutorial.net/async#executeasync) you'll notice they use ExecuteAsync and only receive back the number of rows affected, but they use Query when they want to retrieve actual rows.

[This stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325862/6757848) contains a more detailed explanation of the difference between `Execute` and `Query`.

Comment: It's an INSERT statement, not a SELECT (though the Oracle syntax for "insert many" includes a SELECT subquery). Anyway, using QueryAsync throws the same exception.